# PromisifyAll - Callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird

Either I missunderstood how BlueBird and it's promisify stuff works or I am doing something wrong here. I've got a "upload-handler" which exports one function. This function has a callback

**The upload-handler looks like this (simplified):**

```
function processSourceStrings(fileInformation, callback) {
    var filePath = fileInformation.path
    var fileExtension = path.extname(filePath)
    switch(fileExtension) {
        case '.json':
            processFile(filePath, function(err, result) {
                if(err)
                    callback(err)

                callback(null, result)
            })

        case '.pot':
        case '.po':
            processFile(err, result) {
                if(err)
                    callback(err)

                callback(null, result)
            })
    }
}

module.exports = {
    processSourceStrings: processSourceStrings
}
```

**In my router I promisify the handler like this:**

```
const uploadHandler = Promise.promisifyAll(require('./process-uploads/upload-handler'))
```

When the function is called at runtime (when it processes a file) it throws an exception on the `callback(err)` line, which says:

> TypeError: callback is not a function

**Here I am calling the function from my router.js:**

```
    for(var i=0; i<req.files["sourceStrings"].length; i++) {
        var fileInformation = req.files["sourceStrings"][i]
        var filePath = fileInformation.path
        var targetFilePath = path.join(targetPath, req.files["sourceStrings"][i].filename)
        fileInformation.path = targetFilePath


        mv(filePath, targetFilePath, {mkdirp: true}).then(uploadHandler.processSourceStrings(fileInformation))
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                next(err)
            })
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling this function `processSourceStrings`?

Comment: Your switch statement should have a `break` - if the `'.json'` case is matched then it and the `'.po'` case will run.

Comment: Please show us the code where you are calling this function.

Comment: @RahulArora edited into the thread. It's called from my router.js. KarlReid thanks for the hint :).

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your issue, but `uploadHandler.processSourceStrings` returns a promise, not a function. So you need to put it inside a function in order to have it called by `then`:
`mv(filePath, targetFilePath, {mkdirp: true}).then(function() { return uploadHandler.processSourceStrings(fileInformation); })`

Comment: @JLRishe You were right, certainly saved me some time, thanks for that!

Comment: Notice that you really should promisify `processFile` and let `processSourceStrings` already work with promises instead of that callback solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uploadHandler.processSourceStrings(fileInformation)` is a call to the regular callback based function and this expects a callback as second parameter.

[`Promise.promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

> Promisifies the entire object by going through the object's properties and creating an async equivalent of each function on the object and its prototype chain. **The promisified method name will be the original method name suffixed with suffix (default is "Async")**.

So you would call the promisified version this way:

```
 uploadHandler.processSourceStringsAsync(fileInformation)
```